# Spring boot 1.4.2 - org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot, hibernate-validator

I developed a web app using maven, spring-boot 1.4.2.RELEASE and embedded tomcat server provided by spring boot.I can run the application using *mvn spring-boot:run*. Its works and able to access the jsp pages.

But I'm getting the exception when i package spring-boot application using *(mvn clean package)*. and running by *java -jar app.war*. I cannot figure out why, any solutions or suggestions to fix this problem?

The exception is following.

```
HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP    
exception    
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:615)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:368)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

....
.....
        org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    root cause

```
javax.el.ELException: Provider com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl not found
    javax.el.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:97)
    javax.el.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:193)
    javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance(ExpressionFactory.java:185)
    javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance(ExpressionFactory.java:156)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.PageInfo.<init>(PageInfo.java:79)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:114)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:372)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:349)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:333)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:600)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:368)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    com.codahale.metrics.servlet.AbstractInstrumentedFilter.doFilter(AbstractInstrumentedFilter.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:208)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:185)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
```

.....
.....

org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    root cause

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl
    org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.loadClass(TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.java:74)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    javax.el.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:83)
    javax.el.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:193)
    javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance(ExpressionFactory.java:185)
    javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance(ExpressionFactory.java:156)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.PageInfo.<init>(PageInfo.java:79)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:114)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:372)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:349)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:333)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:600)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:368)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    com.codahale.metrics.servlet.AbstractInstrumentedFilter.doFilter(AbstractInstrumentedFilter.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:208)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:185)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1257)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    com.codahale.metrics.servlet.AbstractInstrumentedFilter.doFilter(AbstractInstrumentedFilter.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
```

Following is my dependency tree

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ sample-webapp -
--
[INFO] com.sample.webapp:sample-webapp:war:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-annotation:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-graphite:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-healthchecks:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-json:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.4:compile
[INFO] +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-jvm:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-servlet:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-servlets:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] +- io.prometheus:simpleclient:jar:0.0.18:compile
[INFO] +- io.prometheus:simpleclient_servlet:jar:0.0.18:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.prometheus:simpleclient_common:jar:0.0.18:compile
[INFO] +- io.prometheus:simpleclient_dropwizard:jar:0.0.18:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-hibernate5:jar:2.8.4:c
ompile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-hppc:jar:2.8.4:compile

[INFO] |  \- com.carrotsearch:hppc:jar:0.7.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.8.4:compi
le
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-json-org:jar:2.8.4:com
pile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.geronimo.bundles:json:jar:20090211_1:compile
[INFO] +- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.4.193:test
[INFO] +- com.jayway.awaitility:awaitility:jar:1.7.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:3.1:test
[INFO] |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
[INFO] +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.2.0:test
[INFO] |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.2.1:test
[INFO] |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.3:test
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.5.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-models:jar:1.5.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spi:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.springfox:springfox-core:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-schema:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-common:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spring-web:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:com
pile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-metadata:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE
:compile
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-bean-validators:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.ryantenney.metrics:metrics-spring:jar:3.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:2.4.6:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.4:compile
[INFO] +- io.gatling.highcharts:gatling-charts-highcharts:jar:2.2.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.11.8:test
[INFO] |  +- io.gatling:gatling-charts:jar:2.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- io.gatling:gatling-core:jar:2.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.gatling:gatling-commons:jar:2.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:jar:2.11.8:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.typesafe:config:jar:1.3.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.dongxiguo:fastring_2.11:jar:0.2.4:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.softwaremill.quicklens:quicklens_2.11:jar:1.4.6:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- com.typesafe.scala-logging:scala-logging_2.11:jar:3.1.0:te
st
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.11:jar:2.4.3:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.typesafe.akka:akka-slf4j_2.11:jar:2.4.3:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-csv:jar:2
.8.4:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- me.chrons:boopickle_2.11:jar:1.1.3:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-java8-compat_2.11:jar:0.7.0:test

[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashma
p-lru:jar:1.4.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.11:jar:1.0.
4:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.github.scopt:scopt_2.11:jar:3.4.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.gatling:jsonpath_2.11:jar:0.6.6:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.gatling.advantageous.boon:boon-json:jar:0.5.7-RC1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- io.gatling.advantageous.boon:boon-reflekt:jar:0.5.7-RC1:te
st
[INFO] |  |  |  +- net.sf.saxon:Saxon-HE:jar:9.7.0-4:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.jodd:jodd-lagarto:jar:3.7:test
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.jodd:jodd-core:jar:3.7:test
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.jodd:jodd-log:jar:3.7:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.tdunning:t-digest:jar:3.1:test
[INFO] |  +- io.gatling:gatling-app:jar:2.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- io.gatling:gatling-http:jar:2.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.asynchttpclient:async-http-client:jar:2.0.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.asynchttpclient:netty-resolver-dns:jar:2.0.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- org.asynchttpclient:netty-resolver:jar:2.0.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- org.asynchttpclient:netty-codec-dns:jar:2.0.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- com.typesafe.netty:netty-reactive-streams:jar:1.0.4:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:linux-x86_64:4.0.36
.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.0.36.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.0.36.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.0.36.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.11:jar:1.0.5:test
[INFO] |  |  +- io.gatling:gatling-jms:jar:2.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jms_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:tes
t
[INFO] |  |  +- io.gatling:gatling-jdbc:jar:2.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- io.gatling:gatling-redis:jar:2.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- net.debasishg:redisclient_2.11:jar:3.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |     \- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.6:test
[INFO] |  |  \- io.gatling:gatling-metrics:jar:2.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |     \- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.8:test
[INFO] |  \- io.gatling:gatling-recorder:jar:2.2.0:test
[INFO] |     +- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-swing_2.11:jar:1.0.2:test
[INFO] |     +- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.54:test
[INFO] |     |  \- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.54:test
[INFO] |     \- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.0.36.Final:test
[INFO] |        +- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.0.36.Final:test
[INFO] |        \- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.0.36.Final:test
[INFO] +- com.jcraft:jzlib:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] +- javax.cache:cache-api:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.5.2:test
[INFO] +- org.ehcache:ehcache:jar:3.1.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-jcache:jar:5.2.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.2.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.
Final:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.20.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |     +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:compil
e
[INFO] |     +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Fin
al:compile
[INFO] |     \- javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |        +- javax.el:el-api:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.jboss.spec.javax.interceptor:jboss-interceptors-api_1.1_s
pec:jar:1.0.0.Beta1:compile
[INFO] |        \- javax.annotation:jsr250-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-envers:jar:5.2.4.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.2.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.postgresql:postgresql:jar:9.4.1212:compile
[INFO] +- org.mapstruct:mapstruct-jdk8:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:1.4.2.RELEASE:compil
e
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.4.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.4.2.RELEASE:c
ompile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:jar:1.4.2
.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.json:json:jar:20140107:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-loader-tools:jar:1.4.2.RELEASE:co
mpile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:1.4.2.RELEASE:com
pile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.4.2.RELEASE:comp
ile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.17:runtime
[INFO] |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.9:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.4.2.RELEAS
E:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.4.2.RELEASE
:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:8.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:8.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.2.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.10.5.RELEASE:compile

[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.4.2.RELEASE
:compile
[INFO] |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail:jar:1.4.2.RELEASE:co
mpile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.mail:javax.mail:jar:1.5.6:compile
[INFO] |     \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:1.4.2.RELEAS
E:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:4.1.3.RELEA
SE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE:
compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.4.2.RELEASE:te
st
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:1.4.2.R
ELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.3.0:test
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.3.4.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-test:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE:te
st
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE
:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:1.4.2.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:jar:1.4.2.RELEA
SE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4:jar:2.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-layout-dialect:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:jar:2.4.7:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.4.2.RELEASE:com
pile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket:jar:1.4.2.RELEA
SE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:4.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-websocket:jar:4.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:jar:0.7.0:compile
[INFO] +- net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:jar:4.7:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cloud-connectors:jar:1.4.
2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-spring-service-connector:jar
:1.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-core:jar:1.2.3.RELEASE:co
mpile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector:jar:1
.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-heroku-connector:jar:1.2.3.R
ELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-localconfig-connector:jar:1.
2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-data:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE:co
mpile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.12.5.RELEASE:com
pile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-messaging:jar:4.1.3.RELEA
SE:compile
[INFO] |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:jar:8.5.6:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler:ecj:jar:4.5.1:provided
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE
:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-acl:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE:
compile
[INFO] +- net.sargue:java-time-jsptags:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-java8time:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE:comp
ile
[INFO] |  \- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:jar:2.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- ognl:ognl:jar:3.0.8:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.unbescape:unbescape:jar:1.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:3.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:jar:3.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec:jar:1.0:com
pile
[INFO] |  \- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
[INFO] +- org.webjars:webjars-locator:jar:0.32:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.webjars:webjars-locator-core:jar:0.30:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] +- org.webjars:sockjs-client:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.webjars:stomp-websocket:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.webjars:bootstrap:jar:3.3.7:compile
[INFO] +- org.webjars:jquery:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.4.2.RELEASE:
compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.6:compile
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:jar:1.4.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Post your pom.xml